# Large number of items in RecyclerView.Adapter - Memory Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Overview**: I'm having a chat application. Till now, I was using CursorAdapter with a Listview to load my chat items in the list. But now, I'm planning to refactor the code to use RecyclerView with RecyclerView.Adapter and a "Load More" functionality like whatsapp.

**Issue**: Memory consumption. With CursorAdapter, items not in viewable area were getting Garbage Collected, but now since I'm using an ArrayList of my CustomModal, once you load all the items in the list (by clicking on the "Load More" button) I'm seeing high memory consumption in the memory logs (No Garbage Collection).

My guess is now, I'm loading all the items in an ArrayList and that is causing the issue. Is that it?

Is there a way to avoid the issue or optimize the problem?

***EDIT***:
Can't post the complete code here, but here is a snippet of the kind of Adapter that I've implemented:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MyModal> mMyModals;

    public MessageAdapter(ArrayList<MyModal> mMyModals) {
        this.mMyModals = mMyModals;
        //... Some fields initialization here
    }

    public void changeList(ArrayList<MyModal> myModals, boolean isLoadMoreEnabled){
        this.mMyModals = myModals;
        //... Some fields initialization here
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void toggleLoadMore(boolean isLoadMoreEnabled){
        if(isLoadMoreEnabled){
            //..Checks if load more is already enabled or not
            //..If not then enables it by adding an item at 0th poition of MyModal list
            //..Then notifyDataSetChanged()
        }else{
            //..Checks if load more is already disabled or not
            //..If not then disables it by removing an item at 0th poition of MyModal list
            //..Then notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        MyViewHolder messageViewHolder = null;
        View itemLayoutView = null;

        MyModal.MessageType messageType = MyModal.MessageType.getMessageTypeFromValue(viewType);
        switch (messageType){
            case MESSAGE_TYPE1:
                itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout1, null);
                messageViewHolder = new Type1ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TYPE2:
                itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
                messageViewHolder = new Type2ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
                break;
        }

        return messageViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyModal myModal = mMyModals.get(position);
        MyModal.MessageType messageType = myModal.getMessageType();
        holder.initialize(myModal);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mMyModals != null)?mMyModals.size():0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mMyModals.get(position).getMessageType().getValue();
    }

    public abstract class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
        }

        public abstract void initialize(MyModal myModal);
    }

    class Type1ViewHolder extends MyViewHolder {

        //...Variables

        public Type1ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            //...variables initialization here
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(MyModal myModal) {
            //...Setting values in view using myModal
        }
    }

    class Type2ViewHolder extends MyViewHolder {

        //...Variables

        public TextViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            //...variables initialization here
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(MyModal myModal) {
            //...Setting values in view using myModal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your adapter class. You might be initiazing more times than needed. WIll check once you post code

Comment: Hey Ragesh, I've updated my question with the code. Can you please help me figure out the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all :

```
   public void changeList(ArrayList<MyModal> myModals, boolean isLoadMoreEnabled){
    this.mMyModals = myModals;
    //... Some fields initialization here
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here you are creating a new arraylist and assigning it to your mMyModals. This means there are 2 arraylists at this point and they take up twice the amount of space than required. GC doesnt work the way you expect it to. Since the arraylist is initialized in your activity it will persist as long as the arraylist persists and so will the initial arraylist.

Instead of creating a new arraylist in your activity and passing it to  changeList. Just clear your old arraylist and pass that.And also in adapter changeList method you can do the below

```
     public void changeList(ArrayList<MyModal> myModals, boolean isLoadMoreEnabled){
    this.mMyModals.clear();
    this.mMyModels.addAll(myModels);
    //... Some fields initialization here
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Please let me know if i am not clear. Also show your activity code if this does not work.

Comment: Thanks @Ragesh, will try it tomorrow.

Comment: That (clear() and addAll() method) actually worked. At least GC is able to do it work now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the whole `ArrayList` and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, try adding the items to the `ArrayList` and then call `notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)`, maybe that could work. Also, you dont have to replace the `Adapter`'s `ArrayList`. Your `Activity`/`Fragment` probably has the same `ArrayList`, just editing this list in your `Activity`/`Fragment` and then calling `notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)` should do the trick. Also, instead of retrieving all the messages, you could also try to only get the next X amount of messages, so you wont retrieve the messages you already retrieved before (if you didn't do that already).

Comment: Thanks Jeffalee, will try it out. But still, if I'm assigning a new object to my arraylist reference, then the old object becomes eligible for GC, right? But I'm not seeing that. My app is consuming the complete 128Mb of memory